# How to read contents of many textboxes to an array?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I have to write a program (C#, WPF), where data is retrieved from ~30 TextBoxes. I'd like to cycle the textboxes through. I tried to create an array of textboxes, but it didn't work very well because in every method I had to repeatedly reinitialize this array.

```
 TextBox[] subjects = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10 };
 TextBox[] credits = { textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16, textBox17, textBox18, textBox19, textBox20 };
 TextBox[] marks = { textBox21, textBox22, textBox23, textBox24, textBox25, textBox26, textBox27, textBox28, textBox29, textBox30 };

Subject.SubjectName = subjects[selection].Text;
Subject.AmountOfCredits= Convert.ToInt32(credits[selection].Text);
Subject.Mark = Convert.ToInt32(marks[selection].Text);
```

Main question is, if there is any other way to cycle through all those controls without creating arrays of textboxes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a DataGrid control? You could have three columns (Subjects, Credits and Marks) and easily get to the selected record via the SelectedItem property?

The other option is to use an ItemsControl. You could style the ItemTemplate to have three textboxes, which you databind to the properties of Subject directly. The ItemsControl's ItemsSource would then be bound to an observable collection of Subjects. For more information on how to do this, go to Microsoft's help on [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could bind each textbox to a property. Then in the setter of each property, you would set the appropriate value in your array.

```
public class test
{
    private string[] _textBoxes;

    // constructor
    public test()
    {
        _textBoxes = new string[30];
    }

    // bind your textboxes to a bunch
    // of properties
    public string Property0
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBoxes[0];
        }
        set
        {
            _textBoxes[0] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Property0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make the arrays global to the form rather than local to a method?  That way you would only create the arrays once (perhaps inside the form's Load() event).

If making the control arrays global is not an option, you could lookup the controls by name (although this is somewhat slower than your array method)

```
string idx = (selection + 1).ToString();  // convert selection to 1-based index string

TextBox subjectText =    (TextBox)FindControl("textBox" + idx);
TextBox amtCreditsText = (TextBox)FindControl("textBox1" + idx);
TextBox marksText =      (TextBox)FindControl("textBox2" + idx);
```